# Qt Creator cannot run HTML5 apps on Ubuntu 13.10, is it broken?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

When attempting the [Ubuntu HTML5 tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/cordova/creating-cordova-ubuntu-qr-code-scanner-html5-app/) on the Ubuntu site, I have just created the template app and am attempting to run it.  When I run it, I get this error:

> Starting ubuntu-html5-app-launcher --www=/home/shah/Code/qrcode-scanner
>
> /usr/bin/ubuntu-html5-app-launcher: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   ubuntu-html5-app-launcher exited with code 127

I am not sure how to resolve this and I cannot find any threads with fixes regarding this problem.  I have tried a `sudo apt-cache search libQt5Core` which indicates `libqt5core5` but I already have that installed, so I'm wondering if something else is wrong.

Comment: @DavidPlanella ? **Shah**, do you have the `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5` file?

Comment: @wilf - That file isn't there, I did a `locate` and found it here: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.   I'm using 64 bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh sorry, mine was for `32bit`, not `64bit` - though if the Qt Creator is 32bit version... you could try `sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5` - as this a library file, it should not cause any damage if it is also elsewhere *(hopefully)*

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed now, it was a packaging issue.